# how to logout from facebook through an alertview button in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have an application in which i  have implemented facebook in my app. In my app i have a page with a label and a button .when i click on the button the login page of facebook is opened.when i enter my username and password and click on the login button the login page dissapears. All this is working fine and but the problem is when i click again my button it should an alertview displaying that "this will logout from your previous account" and on the click of the ok button the  session should get logged out displaying the login page.The problem is when i click the button it directly shows the login page without showing the alertview.Please help me in solving this problem.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing any of your code, i'm not too sure exactly how your logic is showing the alert, but if i was to show a confirmation alert, it would look something like this

```
- (IBAction)logoutButton_touchUpInside
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    [alert setTitle:@"Please Confirm"];
    [alert setMessage:@"are you sure?"];
    [alert setDelegate:self];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"No"];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

And implement the delegate method to catch the button click:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        // Yes, do something
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        // No, cancel etc...
    }
}
```